# JavaScript: Comparing Two objects in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm new to this world of vanilla javascript. I've been trying complete some challenges but it seems like I'm unable to find the solution to a challenge.

The task is:*"Sort array by object property"*

1. Write a function that takes an array of objects as an argument
2. Sort the array by property b in ascending order
3. Return the sorted array

```js
function arraySorter(arr) {
  return arr
    .map((e) => {
      return Object.values(e);
    })
    .filter((e, i) => {
      console.log(e[1]);
      return;
    });
}

console.log(
  arraySorter([
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 5, b: 4 },
  ])
);
```

*Expected output*

```js
//expected output: [{a:1,b:2},{a:5,b:4}]
// expected output: [{a:5,b:4},{a:2,b:10}]
```

Comment: `function arraySorter(arr){
   return 
}` ... that returns `undefined` ... did you forget some code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No @JaromandaX, I was just trying to show the format of the solution I was looking for. 
This is the furthest I could go-

function arraySorter(arr) {
  return arr
    .map((e) => {
      return Object.values(e);
    })
    .filter((e, i) => {
      console.log(e[1]);
      return;
    });
}
String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
console.log(
  arraySorter([
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 5, b: 4 },
  ])
);

But I don't think this is it.

Comment: you should show your attempts in teh question, lest it look like you're using stackoverflow as a homework answering service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `sort` with numbers.

1. sorting ascending ( first argument - second argument )
2. sorting descending ( second argument - first argument ),

as `sort` function should `return`

1. positive number if the first argument is bigger than the second argument.
2. negative number if second argument is bigger than first argument.
3. zero if both are equal.

   ```js
   function arraySorter(arr) {
      return arr.sort((x, y) => x.b - y.b)
   }

   console.log(arraySorter([{a:1,b:2},{a:5,b:4}])) //expected output: [{a:1,b:2},{a:5,b:4}]
   console.log(arraySorter([{a:2,b:10},{a:5,b:4}])) //Expected output: [{a:5,b:4},{a:2,b:10}]
   console.log(arraySorter([{a:1,b:7},{a:2,b:1}])) //Expected output: [{a:2,b:1},{a:1,b:7}]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method available on arrays.

You can also make your sort function more generic by accepting the key according to which the objects need to sorted and the order for sorting.

```js
function sortArrayOfObjects(arr, sortKey, isAscending = true) {
  return [...arr].sort(({ [sortKey]: a }, { [sortKey]: b }) =>
    isAscending ? a - b : b - a
  );
}

console.log(sortArrayOfObjects([{ a: 5, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 4 }], "a"));
console.log(sortArrayOfObjects([{ a: 2, b: 10 }, { a: 5, b: 4 }], "b"));
console.log(sortArrayOfObjects([{ a: 1, b: 7 }, { a: 2, b: 1 }], "a", false));
```

Comment: But it has two arguments. I'm looking for the solution from a single argument function.

Comment: @BhaskarDeb You can hardcode the `sortKey` or provide a default value, but I'd recommend keeping the function more generic.